# Homotopy type of smooth manifold with boundary

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

It seems very likely to me that a $n$-dimensional smooth manifold with boundary has the homotopy type of a $(n-1)$-dimensional CW complex. Is that true? Does the manifold need to be compact? What about $n$-dimensional open manifolds?

Comment: It can only true if you require that $M$ is connected or that all components of $M$ have a nonempty boundary. Otherwise it may have a component $S^n$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, these obvious assumptions should be added to the question. But then?

Comment: For a discussion in dimension 2, with allusions to higher dimensions, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces/92723#92723).